# Calling instance methods from within blocks

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I tried to implement a class allowing its subclasses to save method blocks for get them executed later. It work's, but it seems I took the wrong way. Have a look at this:

```
class SuperKlass  
  def self.exec_later(&block)
    @@block_for_later = block
  end

  def exec_now
    return unless @@block_for_later
    @@block_for_later.call
  end
end

class ChildKlass < SuperKlass
  exec_later do
    child_method
  end

  def child_method
    puts "Child method called"
  end
end

test_klass = ChildKlass.new
test_klass.exec_now
```

If I try to execute this piece of code, the call to `child_method` in the block results in a method-missing error. Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong, and what's the right way to add functionality like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The block `exec_later` is running in the context of `ChildKlass`, not the instance `test_klass`. As `child_method` is an instance method, it isn't found on `ChildKlass`.

UPDATE: I found a solution:

```
  def exec_now
    return unless @@block_for_later
    instance_eval &@@block_for_later
  end
```

Comment: Great, this works. Allthough I knew about instance_eval, I didn't know that it can be used to execute a block with the ampersand. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: I am very happy to can help you, because I'm learning metaprogramming now, and I could use some of new knowledge with success. :) About the use of ampersand, I learned a lot of method/proc calls details [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls#The_ampersand_.28.26.29). I hope it can be useful to you, too.

Comment: This link really is helpfull for me, thank's again :) I found another link [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/54096#32642) which could probably helpful, about passing arguments if a block is called this way.